# Angular 2 : list is not refresh on running IOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I work in Angular 2 project (and also use Ionic 2).

In my project, I have a page to display pictures-list.

User can add/remove pictures (by cordova-camera plugin).

My problem is: when user remove picture, I remove it from list behind UI.
**Debugging at chrome - work nice.
BUT, try emulate on IOS, or really test on Smart-phone**, when user delete picture the view is doesn't get refresh till he press any button.
What should I do???

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-col width-50 *ngFor="let picture of pictures">
        <div>
            <button (click)="checkAsGood(picture)">I like</button>
            <button (click)="deletePicture(picture)"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img [src]="picture.src" />
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-list>
```

**Java Script:**

```
 private deletePicture(pictureRecord:Picture) {
var self = this;
  self.pictureService.deleteUserPicture(pictureRecord).then(function deleteSucceeded() {

    self.pictures.splice(self.pictures.indexOf(pictureRecord), 1);
  }, function deleteFaild(error) {
    self.messagesService.showToastMessage(error.code)
  });
}
```

Comment: if you use `() => {` instead of `function () {` then you don't need `self` because `this` will do what you expect.

Comment: Also for iOS related issues, try it on safari, you're bound to have the same issues and safari also has an OK debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call change detection explicitly

```
  class MyComponent {

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    private deletePicture(pictureRecord:Picture) {
      this.pictureService.deleteUserPicture(pictureRecord).then(() => {
        this.pictures.splice(this.pictures.indexOf(pictureRecord), 1);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }, (error) => {
        this.messagesService.showToastMessage(error.code)
      });
    }
  }
```

or ensure the callback is executed in Angulars zone already in the service using `zone.run(...)`.

It looks like some functionality your `pictureService` is using functionality that isn't fully covered by the zone.js package on IOS.